# is there a way to pass value/text/data from form to another form

Tags: c#, database

I have a form contains `StaffID` and more and the form have a Search-button that when I press it it will open another form with a `DataGridView` then when I double-click a row it will pass the selected data to another form

the first form here [First Form here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H9wd.png)

second form here [Second form where data came from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7L2D.png)

so on the second form I will double click a row then it should send a data string to staffID textbox on the first form

here is my code (btw the to open the form2 is **form2.ShowDialog()**)

my code to send data to the first form

```
private void dgw_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    FrmStaff frmStaff = new FrmStaff();

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgw.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        frmStaff.txtStaffID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

the textbox is also modifiers : **Public**

but the problem is I don't get the value....

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do it. By using the global variable class with static variables initialize this global class in the main method only.

code should be like shown below

```
public class Globalvaribale()
{
  public static string sVale="";
  public static string sVale1="";
}
```

In Main Method

```
 private void dgw_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        FrmStaff frmStaff = new FrmStaff();

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgw.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Globalvaribale.sValue= row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string getdata = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
             Globalvaribale.sValue1 = "Sample";
            MessageBox.Show(getdata);
        }
    }
```

You can use the same variables with the same value complete application as well.

Comment: Sorry about my codes i edit it now so the class Globalvariable() should be on the form where the data came from? or form where the data sending?

Comment: Globalvariable() separate class file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting it to show the new form on the double click event as shown I would modify the FrmStaff to take the parameters into the constructors.

```
// In FrmStaff file
private string _staffId;

public FrmStaff(string staffId)
{
    _staffId = staffId;
}
```

Then when you do the

```
frmStaff.Show()
```

In the calling screen it will have the passed staffId internal to it now

Hope this helps?